# Orientation change nullifies SensorManager reference

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-location, sensormanager

I am making an application that attaches both location and sensor listeners, so that it can then record changes from them into a file.

What's strange is that one of the phones using the application was Force Closing in some instances, which I narrowed down to orientation changes: if the phone changed orientation during recording, the SensorManager attribute I had stored inside the activity as 'mSensorManager' would then be set to null.

This leads into my question: should I not store the SensorManager reference, due to it being a bad design choice? Or is it okay, and should I just check if the reference is null before using it?

**EDIT**: Two things to add:

1. I found out that not only the accelerometer and magnetometer attributes were also nullified (which kind of made sense), but also
   the locationmanager (which doesn't make much change, as it has
   nothing to do with orientation determination);
2. Should I store those attributes inside something other than the activity, that won't nullify the references upon an orientation
       change?

**What did it for me:**
Correcting listener, manager and sensor instantiation to be done from within the activity's lifecycle. Then the only problem was with the wake-lock, which was destroyed, but I needed to be kept through the orientation changes. I changed it to be acquired during the activity lifecycle aswell, albeit in a different phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What did it for me:** Correcting listener, manager and sensor instantiation to be done from within the activity's lifecycle. Then the only problem was with the wake-lock, which was destroyed, but I needed to be kept through the orientation changes. I changed it to be acquired during the activity lifecycle aswell, albeit in a different phase.

Answer (score 1):

1. try after adding this line inside activity tag in you manifest

   ```
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
   ```

   I guess it is nullifying because on orientation change `onCreate` is
   called for that activity
2. Try to save values using [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: I haven't heard about shared preferences, but the name hints that those are meant for system objects, rather than application settings. Regardless, my 'onCreate' method probably instantiates system objects which could be pushed further down the execution path, maybe I'll try that and looking at the saved instance bundle.

Comment: Nothing in the bundle, but your post kind of pointed me in the right direction. I started instantiating the sensor and manager objects in the onCreate method, but then the toggle button I had blew up because of a screen lock object I had. This hinted at the fact that I lost my wakeLock variable in the meanwhile, which is a completely different problem. Maybe it should be static?

Comment: I feel you should get credit for guiding me towards the right path, but the answer isn't what solved it for me, but the awareness that orientation changes trigger an activity restart. What should we do?

Comment: Answer for this lies in the 1st point of the answer to add android:configChanges..and if it guided u in right direction u can upvote the answer